# Identifying the first element on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I use python with selenium and I am using the following to identify the 2 web elements on my page:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')]"))
```

I am trying to select/identify the first one using:

```
"//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')][0]"
```

For some reason it does not work. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To identify the first matching element, you can use the find_elements method instead, and then access the first element of the returned list.

> elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,
> '/checkout')]")
> first_element = elements[0]

- Alternatively, you can use the find_element method with the find_elements locator strategy to achieve the same result in a single line:

> first_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@href,
> '/checkout')])[1]")

Comment: Thank you @Samira Kumar Nanda
Your following suggestion worked:

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')])[1]")
I was doing the following instead, which was wrong:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')][0]"))

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')][0]
```

To: This will locate the first occurrence of the matching node which it finds from the top of the DOM tree.

```
(//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')])[1]
```

Code should look like:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("(//a[contains(@href, '/checkout')])[1]"))
```

Comment: Thanks @shawn but it did not work.